# toTitleCase to ignore ordinals in C#

Tags: c#, .net, regex, string

I'm trying to figure out a way to use toTitleCase to ignore ordinals.  It works as I want it to for all string except for ordinals (e.g. 1st, 2nd, 3rd becomes 1St, 2Nd, 3Rd).

Any help would be appreciated.  A regular expression may be the way to handle this, I'm just not sure how such a regex would be constructed.

Update:  Here is the solution I used (Using John's answer I wrote below extension method):

```
public static string ToTitleCaseIgnoreOrdinals(this string text)
{
    string input = System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.TextInfo.ToTitleCase(text);
    string result = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Replace(input, "([0-9]st)|([0-9]th)|([0-9]rd)|([0-9]nd)", new System.Text.RegularExpressions.MatchEvaluator((m) => m.Captures[0].Value.ToLower()), System.Text.RegularExpressions.RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
    return result;
}
```

Comment: This is not a bad question, as much as it has been downvoted.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
string input =  System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.TextInfo.ToTitleCase("hello there, this is the 1st");
string result = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Replace(input, "([0-9]st)|([0-9]th)|([0-9]rd)|([0-9]nd)", new System.Text.RegularExpressions.MatchEvaluator((m) =>
{
    return m.Captures[0].Value.ToLower();
}), System.Text.RegularExpressions.RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
```

Comment: can use this regex "([0-9]+[a-zA-Z]+)" , covers more ground

Comment: can use this regex "([0-9]+[a-zA-Z]+)" , covers more ground, this wont work as it will not make 4seasons to 4Seasons

Answer (score 3):

You can use regular expressions to check if the string starts with a digit before you convert to Title Case, like this:

```
if (!Regex.IsMatch(text, @"^\d+"))
{
   CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.TextInfo.toTitleCase(text);
}
```

Edit: forgot to reverse the conditional... changed so it will apply toTitleCase if it DOESN'T match.

2nd edit: added loop to check all words in a sentence:

```
string text = "150 east 40th street";



            string[] array = text.Split(' ');


            for (int i = 0; i < array.Length; i++)
            {
                if (!Regex.IsMatch(array[i], @"^\d+"))
                {
                    array[i] = CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.TextInfo.ToTitleCase(array[i]);
                }
            }


            string newText = string.Join(" ",array);
```

Comment: But the string can contain digits, only words(?) which are ordinals should be ignored. So `100m` should become `100M` because it's not an ordinal.

Comment: This will work, however I need to loop through each word in the string...  Otherwise this will only work on the first word in a string.

Comment: @TimSchmelter - I should have included an example.  The string could be something like "150 east 40th street" and should result in "150 East 40th Street"

Comment: @TimSchmelter - I upvoted this answer, your solution isn't terrible its just not maintainable for all ordinals

Comment: @Ben: what is the desired result for this: `population 10m, 31th 11th`? The correct result (if your requirement makes sense) is: `Population: 10M, 31Th 11th`

Comment: @TimSchmelter - that's a good point, but I feel like this is easier than creating an explicit list of ordinals... your solution would be more error-resistant if Ben is expecting 'words' like that in the string.

Answer (score 1):

This would work for those strings, you could override ToTitleCase() via an Extension method.

```
string s = "1st";

if (   s[0] >= '0' && s[0] <= '9' ) {
   //this string starts with a number
   //so don't call ToTitleCase()
}
else {  //call ToTileCase() }
```

Comment: This will only work for ordinals 1st through 9th.  What about ordinals such as 10th, 21st, 103rd, etc?

Comment: you don't need the `s.Length`, if the string starts with a number you could not execute ToTitleCase()

Comment: Whatever happened to stuff like `s[0] >= '0' && s[0] <= '9'`? Why the magic numbers?

Comment: I agree the OP should define his own `ToTitleCase` method instead of trying to undo the undesired effects of the `TextInfo` one.  There are also words like 'and', 'of', 'the' that all become capitalized and would not look good in a street address.

Comment: @Jashaszun, I'm old school but yes that is definitely more readable, will change.

Answer (score 1):

You could simply use `String.Replace` (or `StringBuilder.Replace`):

```
string[] ordinals = { "1St", "2Nd", "3Rd" };  // add all others
string text = "This is just sample text which contains some ordinals, the 1st, the 2nd and the third.";
var sb = new StringBuilder(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture.TextInfo.ToTitleCase(text));
foreach (string ordinal in ordinals)
    sb.Replace(ordinal, ordinal.ToLowerInvariant());
text = sb.ToString();
```

> this is not elegant at all. It requires you to maintain an infinite
>   list of ordinals on the first line. I'm assuming that's why someone
>   downvoted you.

It's not elegant but it works better than other simple approaches like the regex. You want to title-case *words* in  longer text. But only words which are not ordinal-numbers. An ordinal number is f.e. 1st, 2nd or 3rd and 31st but not 31th. So the simple regex sollutions will fail fast. You also want to title-case words like `10m` to `10M` (where M could be the abbreviation for million).

So i don't understand why it's so bad to maintain a list of ordinal numbers.

You could even generate them automatically with an upper-limit, for example:

```
public static IEnumerable<string> GetTitleCaseOrdinalNumbers()
{
    for (int num = 1; num <= int.MaxValue; num++)
    {
        switch (num % 100)
        {
            case 11:
            case 12:
            case 13:
                yield return num + "Th";
                break;
        }

        switch (num % 10)
        {
            case 1:
                yield return num + "St"; break;
            case 2:
                yield return num + "Nd"; break;
            case 3:
                yield return num + "Rd"; break;
            default:
                yield return num + "Th"; break;
        }
    }
}
```

So if you want to check for the first 1000 ordinal numbers:

```
foreach (string ordinal in GetTitleCaseOrdinalNumbers().Take(1000)) 
   sb.Replace(ordinal, ordinal.ToLowerInvariant());
```

---

**Update**

For what it's worth, here is my try to provide an efficient way that really checks words (and not only substrings) and skips `ToTitleCase` on words which really represent ordinal numbers(so not `31th` but `31st` for example). It also takes care of separator chars that are not white-spaces (like dots or commas):

```
private static readonly char[] separator = { '.', ',', ';', ':', '-', '(', ')', '\\', '{', '}', '[', ']', '/', '\\', '\'', '"', '"', '?', '!', '|' };

public static bool IsOrdinalNumber(string word)
{
    if (word.Any(char.IsWhiteSpace))
        return false; // white-spaces are not allowed
    if (word.Length < 3)
        return false;
    var numericPart = word.TakeWhile(char.IsDigit);
    string numberText = string.Join("", numericPart);
    if (numberText.Length == 0)
        return false;
    int number;
    if (!int.TryParse(numberText, out number))
        return false; // handle unicode digits which are not really numeric like ۵

    string ordinalNumber;
    switch (number % 100)
    {
        case 11:
        case 12:
        case 13:
            ordinalNumber = number + "th";
            break;
    }

    switch (number % 10)
    {
        case 1:
            ordinalNumber = number + "st"; break;
        case 2:
            ordinalNumber = number + "nd"; break;
        case 3:
            ordinalNumber = number + "rd"; break;
        default:
            ordinalNumber = number + "th"; break;
    }

    string checkForOrdinalNum = numberText + word.Substring(numberText.Length);
    return checkForOrdinalNum.Equals(ordinalNumber, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase);
}

public static string ToTitleCaseIgnoreOrdinalNumbers(string text, TextInfo info)
{
    if(text.Trim().Length < 3)
        return info.ToTitleCase(text);

    int whiteSpaceIndex = FindWhiteSpaceIndex(text, 0, separator);
    if(whiteSpaceIndex == -1)
    {
        if(IsOrdinalNumber(text.Trim()))
            return text;
        else
            return info.ToTitleCase(text);
    }

    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    int wordStartIndex = 0; 
    if(whiteSpaceIndex == 0)
    {
        // starts with space, find word
        wordStartIndex = FindNonWhiteSpaceIndex(text, 1, separator);
        sb.Append(text.Remove(wordStartIndex)); // append leading spaces
    }

    while(wordStartIndex >= 0)
    {
        whiteSpaceIndex = FindWhiteSpaceIndex(text, wordStartIndex + 1, separator);
        string word;
        if(whiteSpaceIndex == -1)
            word = text.Substring(wordStartIndex);
        else
            word = text.Substring(wordStartIndex, whiteSpaceIndex - wordStartIndex);
        if(IsOrdinalNumber(word))
            sb.Append(word);
        else
            sb.Append(info.ToTitleCase(word));
        wordStartIndex = FindNonWhiteSpaceIndex(text, whiteSpaceIndex + 1, separator);
        string whiteSpaces;
        if(wordStartIndex >= 0)
            whiteSpaces = text.Substring(whiteSpaceIndex, wordStartIndex - whiteSpaceIndex);
        else
            whiteSpaces = text.Substring(whiteSpaceIndex);
        sb.Append(whiteSpaces); // append spaces between words
    }

    return sb.ToString();
}

public static int FindWhiteSpaceIndex(string text, int startIndex = 0, params char[] separator)
{
    bool checkSeparator = separator != null && separator.Any();
    for (int i = startIndex; i < text.Length; i++)
    {
        char c = text[i];
        if (char.IsWhiteSpace(c) || (checkSeparator && separator.Contains(c)))
            return i;
    }
    return -1;
}

public static int FindNonWhiteSpaceIndex(string text, int startIndex = 0, params char[] separator)
{
    bool checkSeparator = separator != null && separator.Any();
    for (int i = startIndex; i < text.Length; i++)
    {
        char c = text[i];
        if (!char.IsWhiteSpace(text[i]) && (!checkSeparator || !separator.Contains(c)))
            return i;
    }
    return -1;
}
```

Note that this is really not tested yet but should give you an idea.

Comment: this is not elegant at all.  It requires you to maintain an infinite list of ordinals on the first line.  I'm assuming that's why someone downvoted you.

Comment: @Ben: maybe my understanding of an ordinal number is wrong, but if you want to ignore only real ordinal numbers you should title-case `31th` to `31Th` because the correct number is `31st`. That's why i'm using a "dictionary". I've added a way to fill it automatically. But i agree that this is not the best approach. I would use a `StringBuilder` to create my own `ToTitleCase` by looping all characters.

Comment: @ben: note that i've provided another (efficient) way which does not need a list of ordinal numbers and also handles edge cases like other separators than spaces. Note that it is insufficiently tested.

Answer (score 1):

I would split the text up and iterate through the resulting array, skipping things that don't start with a letter.

```
        using System.Globalization;

        TextInfo textInfo = new CultureInfo("en-US", false).TextInfo;

        string[] text = myString.Split();
        for(int i = 0; i < text.Length; i++)
        {   //Check for zero-length strings, because these will throw an
            //index out of range exception in Char.IsLetter
            if (text[i].Length > 0 && Char.IsLetter(text[i][0]))
            {
                text[i] = textInfo.ToTitleCase(text[i]);
            }

        }
```

Comment: But how do you want to get the resulting string? `String.Split()` splits by all white-space characters including also tabs or newline characters. That is a good thing but it is impossible to revert it. So you don't know which word was separated by a space and which by a newline. You could presume spaces but the result would be somewhat arbitrary: `string.Join(" ", text)`.

Comment: That's true. I had assumed that myString, since it is supposed to be cased like a title, is short and contains only spaces, like a book title or something.